# how to take all n element in a queue in list of list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I take first element from all list and also second element from all list and so on. Imagine I have list inside list

```
lst = [[3942, 3969, 3078], [1111, 1664, 1565], [4367, 4600, 3486], [1562, 1957, 2061]]
```

How can I get all first element of list and change it into tuple for all element in the list.

I tried list = [list[0]for list in list] but it gives me only the first element of each list.

Expected output

> [(3942,1111,4367,1562),(3969,1664,4600,1957),(3078,1565,3486,2061)]

Comment: This is what [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) is for. Also, don't use `list` as a variable, it overrides the built-in.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your need, I think one possible solution is to parse it as a 2D array and find the transpose of it.

```
import numpy as np
ll = [[3942, 3969, 3078],
      [1111, 1664, 1565],
      [4367, 4600, 3486],
      [1562, 1957, 2061]]
llt = np.transpose(ll)
new_tuple_list = [tuple(l) for l in llt]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach

```
from operator import itemgetter 

test = [[3942, 3969, 3078], [1111, 1664, 1565], [4367, 4600, 3486], [1562, 1957, 2061]]
result = []

for i in range(0, len(test) - 1):
    result.append(tuple(map(itemgetter(i), test)))

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't be more simple than this as pointed out by Mark:

```
temp = list(zip(*lst))
```

which returns

```
[(3942, 1111, 4367, 1562), (3969, 1664, 4600, 1957), (3078, 1565, 3486, 2061)]
```

See Python's [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 'list'as a variable as it is  key word. Anyways,you can do something like this:

```
    lit = [[3942, 3969, 3078], [1111, 1664, 1565], [4367, 4600, 3486]]       
    n = len(lit[0])
    final_li = []
    for i in range(0,n):
      new_li = [l[i]for l in lit]
      final_li.append(new_li)
    print(final_li)
```